# C# .NET Resources

Tags: c#, .net, resources

Is it a good practice to load configuration data for a application through the use of Resources ?

Please let me know.

I am actually working with the Robotics studio and I don't think there is any other way of loading a configuration.

Comment: Its good practice to do something that works. If thats the only way then do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the data you want to load, you could use the [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) features of .NET.

> Application settings enable you to store and retrieve property
>   settings and other information for your application dynamically. They
>   also enable you to maintain custom application and user preferences on
>   the client computer.

If you want to load a large amount of data, then resources (external or embedded) might be a better idea.

Comment: thanks ... i will look at the application settings. as Davide mentions below resources is probably not the way to go in my case.

Answer (score 4):

if you are talking about embedded resources compiled inside the executable or the assembly surely is not a good idea because whenever you need to change the configuration you would need to recompile/build and deploy again.

Configuration should be in config files or database so you can easily react to changes in your environment without building and deploy again.