# A way to load XML files once .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, resources

Actually i'm using xml files for my web pages configuration , xml files contain everything and all the controls/content is loadded through theese XML files and it works , theese config files can change on the fly , and web pages just change their layout/content no need to recompile/redeploy , and i must keep this way of doing things.

The problem is that i'm loading these files like 20 times per page and when i want to access them from my classes/ashx files , i just keep opening them. Is there a way to load xml Files as they were globalresources  , and access content from my classes/cs/ashx files?

> the problem with global resources is that if add them as emmbded
>   resources , i can't change them without recompling them refering to
>   [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282949/c-net-resources)  . Correct me if i'm wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to change these files in runtime or just read them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your files in [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx), [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx), [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) or [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) objects.

I think most preferably for is [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx) object, because you can add some [dependencies based on files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx), and your objects will be automatically updated:

```
Cache.Insert("CacheItem4", "Cached Item 4", new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml")));
```

Comment: Thanks , i've never thought of it this way.

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this, I use a helper:

```
public class CacheUtil
{
    private static readonly object locker=new object();
    public static T GetCachedItem<T>(string cacheKey,
                                     Func<T> valueCreateFunc, 
                                     TimeSpan duration)
    {
        var expirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow + duration;
        var cachedItem = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
        if (cachedItem == null)
        {
            lock(locker)
            {
                cachedItem = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
                if (cachedItem == null)
                {
                    cachedItem = valueCreateFunc();
                    HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(cacheKey,
                                          cachedItem,
                                          null,
                                          expirationTime,
                                          Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                                          CacheItemPriority.High,
                                          null);
                }
            }

        }
        return (T) cachedItem;
    }
}
```

which I would use something like this:

```
CacheUtil.GetCachedItem(
    "someUniqueKey",
    ()=>{ //fetch resource from disk
          return value;},
    TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
)
```

The supplied delegate will only be invoked once per day. If the item is already in cache, the delegate will not be invoked again.

Comment: It would be better to use a CacheDependency to expire the cache rather than a duration.  That way the cache would be updated as soon as the file changed but otherwise not (apart from when asp.net decides to expire the cache for its own reasons.)

Comment: Yes. CacheDependency is new to me and I've been looking at the docs since reading some of the other answers and thinking that it might be more useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create wrapper for accessing your files which will have properties like:

```
public class MyMarkupProvider
{
    public XDocument HomePageLayout {get;set;}
}
```

Also it would be create to cache these files. Take a look on using cache and file CacheDependency: [Cache files using ASP.NET Cache Dependency](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=331)